# Does the Android Open Source Project build system support exceptions and RTTI?

Tags: android, exception, android-build

I am building Android from source using the Android build system.  I have some C++ code which throws an exception, but it will not build:

```
// test.cpp exceptions
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main () {
      try
      {
        throw 20;
      }
      catch (int e)
      {
        cout << "An exception occurred. Exception Nr. " << e << endl;
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

I get this error:

```
test.cpp:10: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for int'
```

I have been told by some other engineers that the Android OS toolchain does not support exceptions.  Can anyone confirm this?

Please note that I am ***not*** asking about the NDK toolchain.